# SFMC Custom Activity - Save, Publish, Validate, and Execute not firing

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest, custom-activity

I'm currently having some issues getting the Publish, Save, Validate, and Execute event to come back to my Custom Activity. I've tried looking at a few different answers for similar issues, but they don't seem to help me out in my case. If it makes a difference, my Custom Activity is hosted on an IIS Web Server. I setup tracing though Microsoft Message Analyzer and am expecting to see the URLs I specified in there.

When a Journey using My Custom Activity runs, I get this error for my contacts for my REST activity: "Failed - Required attribute but null Configuration field or property. Property/Field name: Publish". I'm pretty sure I'm specifying this in my config.js file. I wouldn't leave it past me to have made a simple mistake though or missed something.

Here's my config.js file with sensitive data removed. I tried a fair amount of things, but with this version I tried to get as close as possible to Salesforce's example:

```
define([], function () {
    return {
        "key": "[key]",
        "workflowApiVersion": "1.1",
        "metaData": {
            "icon": "[url]/icon.png",
            "iconSmall": "[url]/iconSmall.png",
            "category": "message",
            "expressionBuilderPrefix": "[prefix]",
            "isConfigured": false,
            "configurationDisabled": false,
            "configOnDrop": true
        },
        "type": "REST",
        "lang": {
            "en-US": {
                "name": "[name]",
                "description": "[description]"
            }
        },
        "arguments": {
            "execute": {
                "url": "[url]/Execute"
            }
        },
        "configurationArguments": {
            "applicationExtensionKey": "[key]",
            "save": {
                "url": "[url]/Save"
            },
            "publish": {
                "url": "[url]/Publish"
            },
            "validate": {
                "url": "[url]/Validate"
            }
        },
        "wizardSteps": [
            {
                "label": "Select Template",
                "key": "selectTemplate"
            },
            {
                "label": "Customer",
                "key": "configureCustomer"
            },
            {
                "label": "Message",
                "key": "configureMessage"
            },
            {
                "label": "Offer",
                "key": "configureOffer"
            },
            {
                "label": "Product",
                "key": "configureProduct"
            },
            {
                "label": "Confirm",
                "key": "confirm"
            }
        ],
        "userInterfaces": {
            "configModal": {
                "width": 850,
                "height": 600,
                "fullscreen": false,
                "url": "[url]"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, cant tell from the code, but can you confirm you are updating the activity isconfigured=true upon configuring the activity? Also, any particular reason you use js? The default salesforce looks for is json so maybe it expects slightly different things if using js?

Comment: I was using config.js as I couldn't get config.json to load. I just investigated this and found that it was a problem with my website building rather than SFMC. That being said, i still get the same error message using config.json instead of config.js.

And yep, I'm setting isconfigured to true after saving the Activity.

Comment: Hmm ok..when you try and hit this endpoints manually using the url plus publish can you see any traffic? (Even if it generates an error).

Comment: Doug, Yep, I just verified I can still hit the URLs and see the requests in my IIS Logger. I tried with both a POST and GET request.

Comment: So knowing that is working, I checked my examples. This is a link to an example app i have and there is a few things extra in comparison to yours which should help :D 
https://jsonbin.io/5a3cd08b4d644f441d171867

Comment: Thanks for the sample! I tried it, but still am not seeing it work. Just one probably dumb question, what are you using in the customerKey value? I've tried the JWT Signing token I get from my installed package and the client id for my Marketing Cloud App with no luck.

Comment: I am using an application key under Admin -> Data management -> key management, but that wouldnt stop the request from being sent to the microservice :( not really sure at this point what could help, im sorry.

Comment: Doug, no worries, thanks for your help. I have a feeling it's something with the environment I'm using as it was just a demo environment. I'll be moving to a proper environment in the future and hopefully have an update.

Comment: what was the solution at the end ?